# MySQL insertar NULL en campo DATETIME

Tags: mysql, python

Tengo una tabla con varios campos DATETIME configurados con valor por defecto NULL.  Me han pedido que si un registro no tiene un tiempo en uno de los valores, se haga un INSERT con el valor NULL.  Si en el campo a realizar INSERT tiene día y hora lo ingresa perfectamente y si está vacío le indico que en el campo se haga un INSERT de 'NULL', pero al ver el registro aparece como 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

¿Cómo puedo realizar un INSERT de NULL para que no aparezca 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Mi código python previo a la instrucción INSERT es:

```
if ultima_fecha == '':
    ultima_fecha = 'NULL'
```

Gracias.

Comment: En python se usa `None` en vez de  `Null`. Y no confundas `None` con `'None'`(string) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/referring-to-the-null-object-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
if not ultima_fecha:
    ultima_fecha = None
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración

Comment: Si bien ese bloque de código podría resolver el problema planteado, una explicación no vendría mal. [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)